# Automator Make an app run if the password is correct, otherwise do something else

Tags: automator

Is there a way to make it so that when I login, the automator asks me for a set password, and if the password is incorrect, it runs an action.

Comment: This doesn't really show any research effort, and also presents as a likely [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Please show what your research has discovered already & what problem you are actually trying to solve, rather than what solution you think you may have found.

Comment: You can (and should) login with a password, which would reasonably ensure that whoever was about to run {whatever app it is} was the rightful user.

Comment: Automator doesn’t have any conditional actions, so you will need to use something such as a script.